# Send a file directly to a printer

Tags: powershell

Within the command window (cmd) I can do a

```
Copy myfile.ps com1*
```

If I run this in Powershell I receive an error message similar to:

English:

> The Path D:\directory\com1 cannot be processed as the destination represents a reserved device name.

German:

> Der Pfad ... kann nicht verarbeitet werden, da das Ziel für einen reservierten Gerätenamen steht.

Is there still a way to send a file directly to a printer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [`Out-Printer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-printer) cmdlet that is used for printing. It looks like the printer needs to be installed in Windows, so direct print into serial port might not work.

Comment: <br>Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jörg If the printing works, check the answer checkmark so that others with same problem see if this solution works or is just an attempt.

Comment: Yes, printing generally works - but I couldn't get my postscript file printed by the postscript processor of the printer.  I tried<br/>  MyFile.ps | Out-Printer  -> Error  
Out-Printer -InputObject MyFile.ps -> The file name itself in one line
Get-Content MyFile.ps | Out-Printer -> The postscript commands  Hello  there

Comment: Being new on Stackoverflow I am still struggling with getting a comment formatted. My visible line breaks (2 spaces at end of line) become never permanent, nor does the At-sign. Sorry.  The last line should read:  <br/>Get-Content MyFile.ps | Out-Printer -> The postscript commands